# Querying any member of a Postgres array type in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Everywhere I looked there were 2 examples

either

```
Book.where("'history' = ANY (subjects)")
```

to query a book with a specific subject in the subject array

or

```
 Book.where("subjects @> ?", '{'history', 'drama'}')
```

to query books that the subjects array has both history and drama

How do I query for books that has either history or drama or both?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I am solving this using

```
query = subject_list.map do |subject|
                "'#{subject}' = ANY(subjects)"
            end.join(" OR ")

Book.where(query)
```